# Resizing image using its data

Tags: c++, image, rescale

I have a C++ program which reads in an image file, deals with the header, and then stores the image's colour data in a pointer to a pointer of chars

```
unsigned char** pixelData = new unsigned char*[header.width*header.height];
for(int i=0;i<header.width*header.height;i++)
    pixelData[i] = new unsigned char[bytes2read]; //bytes2read is 3(rgb) or 4(rgba)
```

If I wanted to then rescale the image to half of its original size, how could I do that? does anyone know of a handy algorithm for this?

Comment: For downscaling, you typically just average the pixel values, but fancy algorithms use bicubic translation). By the way, do you mean a quarter of the size (half each side) or half the size (71% of each side)?

Comment: half each side. im not looking for anything fancy, just a way of using data in a pointer to a pointer to get the smaller image. just proof of concept at the moment.

Comment: Think about it in one dimension first. It's really quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

What about using OpenGL. This is almost trivial to do with OpenGL and the best part is that the operation is GPU accelerated.

Comment: i cant use it, i have to use the data directly

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do that will deliver OK results is to simply average the R,G,B values of each 2x2 pixel square.

Generically what you're doing is applying a filter to the image to determine the new value at each output pixel. The average is what's called a box filter with a width of 2. There are other filters you could use that would deliver better or worse results, but the average is where I'd start.

Comment: if the width or height is odd, is it best to omit the last row/column, or take the average of a 3x2/2x3 box?

Comment: @coolmrcroc, good question. I would take the last pixel without averaging, but anything you've proposed would be good enough for a simple solution. A truly correct solution would involve shifting the filter by 1/2 pixel and creating transparency at the edges.